# Why am I getting "not a number" error in this code?

Tags: ruby, file, debugging

I'm just hoping someone might be able to help me out with this code:

```rb
def write(aFile, number)
  index = 1
  while (index < number)
   aFile.puts(index.to_s)
   index += 1
  end
end

def read(aFile)

  count = aFile.gets
  if (is_numeric?(count))
    count = count.to_i
  else
    count = 0
    puts "Error: first line of file is not a number"
  end

  index = 0
  while (count < index)
    line = aFile.gets
    puts "Line read: " + line
  end
end

# Write data to a file then read it in and print it out
def main
  aFile = File.new("mydata.txt", "w") 
  if aFile  
    write(aFile, 11)
    aFile.close
  else
    puts "Unable to open file to write!"
  end

  aFile = File.new("mydata.txt", "r") 
  if aFile
    read(aFile)
    aFile.close
  else
    puts "Unable to open file to read!"
  end
end

# returns true if a string contains only digits
def is_numeric?(obj)
  if /[^0-9]/.match(obj) == nil
    true
  end
  false
end

main
```

The result I'm trying to get is this:

```
Line read: 0

Line read: 1

...

Line read: 10
```

But I'm getting:

```
Error: first line of file is not a number
```

Why is this the case? Something must be wrong with my code.

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please reduce the code to the bare minimum necessary and show the minimal data file that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
def is_numeric?(obj)
  if /[^0-9]/.match(obj) == nil
    true
  end
  false
end
```

Result of a code block (such as method body) is the last expression evaluated in it. Your `true` becomes the value of the `if` and is ignored, because the next expression evaluated is `false`, which is what is always returned. There are several ways you can improve this.

```
def is_numeric?(obj)
  return true if /[^0-9]/.match(obj).nil?

  false
end

def is_numeric?(obj)
  /[^0-9]/.match(obj).nil?
end

def is_numeric?(obj)
  /[^0-9]/ !~ obj
end

def is_numeric?(obj)
  Integer(obj) rescue false
end
```

And many more.

Comment: I tried using def is_numeric?(obj)
  return true if /[^0-9]/.match(obj).nil?

  false
end
but got the same error. I tried the second one as well and got the same error again.

Comment: @Wah.P: ah, I see. `obj` content is not what you think it is. Try debug-printing it.

Comment: I used puts count/obj and got 0. I don't see what the issue is?

Comment: @Wah.P You use the regex `/[^0-9]/` which matches if one character of the provided string is is not a digit. `gets` returns the line including the newline char at the end (which is not a digit), making the statement always `false`. To resolve it you can use [`chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/String.html#method-i-chomp) to cut off the trailing newline character. (I would use `!obj.match?(/\D/)`)

Comment: @Wah.P "I used puts count/obj" - not debuggy enough. Use `puts obj.inspect` or `p obj`.

Comment: As @3limin4t0r mentions, `match?` certainly deserves a mention. For readability, my preference would be `def natural_number?(obj); obj.match? /\A\d+\z/; end` (a natural number being a non-negative integer) or perhaps `true unless obj.match?(/\D/)`. I tend to avoid negate (`!`) at all cost (perhaps irrationally). I assume the method is called after its argument has been `chomp`ed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland With your solution you could also go for `\Z` instead of `\z`, which allows a trailing newline character (removing the need to `chomp`). `to_i` doesn't care about trailing characters anyway.

Comment: @3limin4t0r, yes (I hadn't thought about that), but I want the argument to have been chomped already. `\Z` would mask that. That's not a problem for this method but it may indicate there's a problem with the calling method. On the other hand, if `\z` is used and the newline is there, `false` will always be returned. For production code, perhaps it would be best if the method used `\z` and raised an exception if the newline were present.